# How much ram can python use?

Tags: python

If I use python (32 bit version) on a machine with for example 64Gb ram , will it be able to use these 64Gb of ram. Or does this depend on the Operating System ?

Comment: are we assuming 64-bit OS?

Comment: yes a 64bit OS is present.

Comment: Try out for yourself:  `gigabyte = ' ' * (1 << 30)` and then `chunk = gigabyte * 10` to allocate 10 gigabyte of ram.

Comment: Are there performance reasons for not using a 64-bit build of Python?

Comment: At the risk of speaking for Ojtwist, I seem to recall some 3rd party libraries are only built for 32bit python

Comment: @Foon is correct. I will try that command when I get my hands on the machine.

Comment: @Alfe Won't that allocate 11GiB?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not itself use any mechanisms for extending past the per-process userspace memory limit of the operating system. There are however modules for and means of doing so. So the answer is "depends on how much work you're willing to do".

Comment: My guess would that be regardless of any tools and extensions used, python 32bit will only be able to address up to 4gb of memory space. I have no hard evidence to prove this but it makes sense.

Comment: @MichaelAquilina  You probably haven't heard of [overlays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlay_%28programming%29) and are probably glad.

Answer (score 2):

Python can use all of the memory allocated to it.  The OS allocates the memory, and usually has limits per process, but there are commands to control those limits. ( 'ulimit' on unix, for example ). But then most OSes use virtual memory, so the OS and it's processes can use more virtual memory than the physical memory available. So its possible for a python program to use more than physical memory. But the OS Virtual memory system controls what pages are in physical memory and what pages are swapped out to disk. So you could be "using" 64 GB of memory, but only a fraction of the most recently used pages are actually in physical memory at any time. And some of that physical memory will hold parts of the OS that run frequently, like those virtual memory allocation functions. Also: the memory allocated to a process is divided and allocated in different ways ( heap vs stack space, for example ). So it's possible to run out of memory for one while there is still lots of unused memory in the other.  So it depends on what you mean by "use" as well as (as the other posted said) "how much work you're willing to do" .  You can probably get 64GB allocated to you, but it's unlikely you can "use" all of physical memory unless you're running an embedded system where you're running as part of the OS.